# Retrieving object from database issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

This has been bothering me for the past hour, and I cannot find out what exactly is going wrong. I am trying to retrieve an object from our database along with several other objects (which return fine). I get an exception

```
object of type 'system.string' cannot be converted to type 'system.int32'
```

Which is odd, because there are only two variables in play here, and both are of datatype **int**. Here is the code.

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult EditGABuyContract(int id)
    {
        var p = PropertyService.GetPropertyBy(id);
        if (p == null)
            return RedirectToRoute(new { Controller = "Dashboard", Action = "Index" });
        var purchase = PropertyService.GetPropertyPurchaseBy(id); //This works just fine
        var buyContract = PropertyService.GetGABuyContractById(id); //This leads to the exception


...
```

**Service**

```
public PropertyGABuyContract GetGABuyContractById(int propertyid) //This leads to an exception
{
    try
    {
        return ((IRepositoryBase)PropertyRepository).GetByPropertyId<PropertyGABuyContract>(propertyid);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        return null;
    }
}

public PropertyPurchase GetPropertyPurchaseBy(int propertyid) //This does NOT lead to an exception
{
    try
    {
        return ((IRepositoryBase) PropertyRepository).GetByPropertyId<PropertyPurchase>(propertyid);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public T GetByPropertyId<T>(int id) where T : PropertyBase, new()
{
    return repo.Single<T>(t => t.PropertyId == id); //Exception occurs here for only GetGABuyContract() method and not for the GetPropertyPurchaseById() method
}
```

This exception does not make sense to me. both objects PropertyPurchase and PropertyGABuyContract inherit from the same PropertyBase class from which the PropertyId is derived.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be `PropertyId` is defined as an `int` in one type and a `string` in the other.

If so this should work:

```
t => int.Parse(t.PropertyId.ToString()) == id
```

or you could change the repository item to int.

Comment: Nope. I tried t => int.Parse(t.PropertyId.ToString()) == int.Prase(id.toString()) as well and it still returned the same error. PropertyId is defined as an int in both tables in SQL, and it's defined in the PropertyBase class as an int. It shouldn't be possible for either the variable I am passing or the field to have a string without getting an error during assignment that I am trying to assign a string to an integer, since I declare them all explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue. One of my other coworkers changed the datatype of one of the fields (not propertyid, another unrelated one) in the database but not in the program. I completed forgot about the change myself. I feel silly now.